# node.js using nested functions from different files

Tags: javascript, node.js, module.exports

I wanted to write a understandable code in node.js, so I want to put some functions, which are used very often, into other node.js files, and access them from there.
So I get a function, which calls a function from another node.js file and in this other node.js file, also another one is called.
Important to know, if I put all in one file, the code works, so it should be an issue with module export and using functions in another file.

I have one file, getting quotes from a decentralised exchange. Looking like this (quoter_uni_v2.js):

```
module.exports = function quotes_uni_v2(tokenIn, tokenOut, amountIn, router) {
  const quotedAmountOut = router.getAmountsOut(amountIn.toString(), [
    tokenIn,
    tokenOut,
  ]);
  return quotedAmountOut;
};
```

And I am importing this function in my second helper file (quotes_5.js) (It is splitted in two files, because in the second one I have to call the function multiple times):

```
var quotes_uni_v2 = require("./quotes_uni_v2");

module.exports = async function (router1, router2, route, amount_wei) {
  console.log(route);
  var amount_Out = await quotes_uni_v2.quotes_uni_v2(
    route[1],
    route[2],
    amount_wei,
    router1
  );
...
  return (
    Math.round(ethers.utils.formatEther(amount_Out[1].toString()) * 100) / 100
  );
};
```

After that I try to call the function in my main.js:

```
const quotes_uni_v2 = require("./quotes_uni_v2");
const quotes_5 = require("./quotes_5");
async function calc(route) {
amountOut = await new quotes_5(
          quickswap_router,
          sushiswap_router,
          route,
          amount_wei
        );
return amountOut;
};
```

But calling the quotes function does not work... The error is:

```
TypeError: quotes_5 is not a constructor...
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with them being in different files. As the error message says, the function you're exporting from `quotes_5.js` isn't a *constructor* function. Why are you using `new` with it?

Comment: I am using new because I found it in an article and it worked with new, if I call quotes_uni_v2() directly from my main.js (So don't have the second file between it). Do I have to put this out of my code?

Comment: You shouldn't (indeed, can't) use `new` with the function you've shown, no. If you found a tutorial using `new` with an `async` function, I would stop reading that tutorial. Even without the `async`, that function would make no sense as a constructor function. You may want to go through some basic JavaScript tutorials for an understanding of what `new` does, what constructor functions are, etc. Happy coding!

Comment: ok I will write it without new and try to learn about async functions (Not that easy I think), But can you maybe help me with this issue? Why I cannot execute this? I think it would be logical, if I import the first file nto the second and the secon (and therefore complete one) into the final one. Why it does not work?

Comment: The question is showing an error about using `new`. I've explained why you shouldn't do that. Without `new`, with what little is in the question, I'd expect the function to at least run. If not, it will produce a *different* error. I suggest deleting this question, playing with it a bit, doing some reading on [`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and posting a new question with a [mcve] **if** you can't work it out.

Comment: (Just as a side note: I cover promises in Chapter 8 of my recent book [*JavaScript: The New Toys*](https://thenewtoys.dev/), and cover `async` functions in Chapter 9.)